# How is the np package able to print temporary messages on the R console?

Tags: r, console

I was going over the following:

```
require('np')
vignette('np', package='np')
```

I noticed as part of the vignette that upon running `npcmstest` some messages were printed to the console and then they disappeared. I ran `body(npcmstest)` to see how and noticed the following code:

```
console <- newLineConsole()
console <- printPush("Bandwidth selection", console)
bw <- npregbw(xdat = xdat, ydat = model$y, ...)
```

However, when i type `newLineConsole` or `printPush` i get an error that it cannot find the function. How is the call to the `npcmstest` then able to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the developer decided not to export these functions (i.e. make available) to users. However, these functions are accessible from the package itself, i.e. `npcmstest` is able to use them.

To access those functions as a user you need to use `:::`:

```
console <- np:::newLineConsole()
console <- np:::printPush("Bandwidth selection", console)
#Bandwidth selection
```